# MonoTouch: UIAlertView with UITextField?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, subclass, uialertview

I'm looking for an `UIAlertView` with a `UITextField`.

I've looked at this sample:
http://www.kevfoo.com/2009/11/monotouch-uialertview-uitextfield-crazy-delicious

But the sample is broken and I'm not skilled enough to fix it. The TextFieldAlertView class' LayoutSubviews gets called 3 times and I think this is messing up the view. I can't seam to fix it.

Are there a working sample of an `UIAlertView` with a `UITextField` that works with MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

This is **not** supported - that means that:

- You can do it;
- A lot of people are doing it;
- It will **break** as often as Appple want to make changes in it;
- **Be warned** that there are reports (try Googling) of people being refused in the AppStore for doing so.

Comment: Thanks ... weird though ... a simple dialog box like that should be public available.